# I would like if there is way to find all the ACM certs using aws acm list-certificates along with validity and domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like if there is way to find all the ACM certs using aws acm list-certificates along with validity and domain name.Because i am looking to find the cert information which are less 30days.

Thanks,
Kalyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with just `list-certificates`, you also need `describe-certificate`:

```
for c in $(aws acm list-certificates --query 'CertificateSummaryList[].CertificateArn' --output text)
    do aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn $c --query 'Certificate.[CertificateArn,DomainName,Status,NotAfter]'
    done
```

If you run this you'll see the information about all of your certificates in the region, with the domains they cover and expiration timestamp. Note that the expiration timestamp is a UNIX timestamp (seconds since epoch), not a date.

Given that you want to test the timestamp, I'd recommend using a language such as Python rather than stringing together CLI invocations.